# Given an image button with borders how to stretch/repeat middle part in CSS for variable length content?

Tags: css, tabs

This is similar to Google Chrome tabs style taken from Soda Theme (Sublime Text 2):

[image: google chrome tabs sublime text 2]

You see how it has 3 parts to it: rising edge, 2-3px flat middle, falling edge.

**Q: How would I, in CSS, "repeat" the middle part and stretch the tab to fit the size of the string?**

Image Dimensions: 42 x 28.

If it helps here is the snippet from the **.sublime-theme** file:

```
    // Tab element
    {
        "class": "tab_control",
        "content_margin": [12, 3, 12, 3],
        "max_margin_trim": 0,
        "hit_test_level": 0.0,
        "layer0.texture": "Theme - Soda/Soda Dark/tab-inactive.png",
        "layer0.inner_margin": [5, 5],
        "layer0.opacity": 1.0
    },
```

Comment: Check out the pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after` and the `content` property

Comment: @crush Will that work? My tab names will be generated dynamically via JavaScript.

Comment: CSS is applied to elements that are appended to the DOM after it's loaded, so yes, it should still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more than a few different ways to accomplish this affect, and it really depends on your preference. As you properly postulated, you need to think of this as 3 different parts. As such, the easiest way would be to split it up into 3 different images.

The solution also depends on what your HTML markup looks like. For example, if you only have:

```
<a class="tab" href="#">My Tab</a>
```

Then you have only one element you can style to make this works (which makes it much harder).

However, if you have a wrapping element around the tab:

```
<li class="tab"><a href="#">My Tab</a></li>
```

You can then use the LI element to help achieve the desired result.

### Single Element

In my first example, you only had the single "anchor" element to work with. Examining your image you want to use for the tab, I can see that it has some beveling, and isn't a simple flat color, or a flat color with a simple border. That means we can't achieve that effect with straight CSS, so we will need CSS to tile the image.

You have two options.

**Option 1**

Split the image into two images, a left and right side, by dividing it right down the middle. Next, in your image editing application, extend your canvas out to the right by, let's say, 200 pixels (or whatever you think the max width of a tab will ever be). Finally, select the farthest right edge (this should be the middle of the tab) and stretch it horizontally all the way to the right border.

What you should end up with is the sloped left side, then an ~200pixel "middle area".

Now you have two images we will call `tab-left-side.png` and `tab-right-side.png`. With these two images, you can achieve the tab affect with the following CSS:

```
.tab {
    background: url(tab-left-side.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px; /* width of the left edge of the tab, before the middle section begins. If you want more horizontal tabbing, add it to this value */
}

.tab:after {
    content: ' ';
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10px; /* width of the right edge of the tab */
    background: url(tab-right-side.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**Option 2**

This option requires splitting your image into three images. You will have `tab-left-side.png`, `tab-middle.png`, and `tab-right-side.png`. As you can guess, you should split the image up into these appropriately.

Now, you can use the CSS:

```
.tab {
    background: url(../images/tab-middle.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px; /* must be same as side widths */
}

.tab:after {
    content: '.';
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999px;
    float: right;
    width: 17px; /* width of the right edge of the tab */
    background: url(../images/tab-right-side.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.tab:before {
    content: '.';
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/tab-left-side.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 17px; /* width of the left edge of the tab */
}
```

### Double Element

The double element is accomplished exactly the same way as Option 1 of the Single Element example, except that you don't have to use the pseudo-class selectors. If you are writing code that has to support older browsers that don't support pseudo-class selectors (or at least `:before` and `:after`) then this is your **only** option.

Again, you split the two images up into `tab-left-side.png` and `tab-right-side.png`.

Then, your CSS:

```
LI.tab {
    background: url(tab-left-side.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px; /* width of the left edge of the tab, before the middle section begins. If you want more horizontal tabbing, add it to this value */
}

LI.tab A {
    content: ' ';
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10px; /* width of the right edge of the tab */
    background: url(tab-right-side.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

It's virtually the same CSS as was in the Option 1 example, except we changed the selectors.

Comment: You could pass an empty string for the content so that you don't need the `text-indent` hack :)

Comment: Ah, okay. Usually I `content:'';` and `display:block;` them [like here.](http://jsfiddle.net/H4ZWL/)

Comment: Weird, I tried that, and it didn't work. Tried sending an empty space too, but no go.

Comment: Huh, strange. Does that Fiddle work for you? It displays for me in Chrome 23.0

Comment: jsfiddle has been broken for me lately, and I haven't been able to view any fiddles.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve a similar result is to use multiple backgrounds and background sizing:

```
li.tab a {
  /* using inline-block for simplicity you could easily switch to
     display block and floats. */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  /* I'm using 75% sizing on my middle image which means my min and
     max calculations work out as follows. This can change depening
     on the images you use. */
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 160px;
  /* height is obviously dependent on many things, I'm using line-height
     to center my text but there are other ways. */
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  /* depending on how your images are designed you may wish to have
     the left and right images layered on top of the middle. To do this
     just reverse the order of the background images. */
  background: 
    url(middle.png) center bottom / 75% 26px no-repeat,
    url(left.png) left bottom no-repeat,
    url(right.png) right bottom no-repeat
  ;
}
```

This does have some prerequisites however:

1. This relies on relatively new css abilities, and as such wont work on older browsers.
2. You have to define a minimum and maximum width that your tabs can be.
3. You have to use two or three images, this wont work with a spritesheet.
4. You need a middle image which has to be rectangluar.